# Grabbing circle doesnt disappear

Tags: 3d-manipulator

[image]
this white circle doesn't disappear, it's not the resizeable grabbing circle, which is activated by pressing g, this one doesn't disappear when selecting different lines and it does grab thing i don't want to move. How can i get rid of it?

Comment: You have Manipulator enabled, it won't go away without explicitly disabling it (Ctrl+Space). Try disabling it and see if it's what you want to do

Comment: are you asking about the white circle with the three arrows coming out of it?

Answer (score 1):

It's the Proportional Editing. You switching between enabling and disabling it by pressing "o" on a keyboard or choosing grey/blue circle icon on the bottom tool bar.

Comment: In the image they are showing, the white circle is not the proportional editing circle.

Comment: do you know any other circle that "grabs things one don't want"? Besides it's enabled on the image, so the guy had to use mouse to make a screenshot, so we can't see the circle of proportional editing cause no transform is being made.

Comment: Hmm, you may be right. I mised the "grab thing I don't want" part. In which case, the image included is not very helpful.

Comment: thx for your answers i get it now, i probably made a different mistake with the grabbing. I was watching tutorials in which the circle didn't appear so i thought that was the reason why i weren't able to follow the instruction. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Now to keep the thread clean, please delete you answer/comment below and mark my answer as the answer. Cheers and happy New Year.

Comment: Probably they mean circle of Transform Manipulator which is in the middle of encircled area. Although this is yet another guess about what is the quesiton about.